# Can't inject a Kotlin service into a Java class

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, gradle

I have the following Kotlin service:

```kotlin
@Service
open class KotlinServiceImpl(private val myRepository: MyRepository) : MyService { ... }
```

The Java class that's trying to get it:

```java
private final MyService MyService;

public MyController(MyService myService) {
  this.myService = myService;
}
```

The error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in MyController required a bean of type 'MyService' that could not be found.

I'm using Gradle, and have the needed dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72'
```

And the relevant Kotlin plugin is also applied:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
```

When I convert the Java interface `MyService` to Kotlin, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/.../MyService

**Using only Java classes solves the problem**.

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, but where is your Java class located and where is @ ComponentScan located? Component scanning by default scans the package and child packages of where the @ ComponentScan annotation is located.

Comment: @DanielJacob I don't think that's the problem, otherwise, it wouldn't have worked when converting the Kotlin file to Java file.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry missed that part. -_-

Comment: question: Is your repository a Spring data JPA repository?

Comment: @DanielJacob Yes.

Comment: In the documentation for Gradle it also says you need plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

Comment: @DanielJacob Tried that as well, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class wasn't available at runtime. I finally noticed that our build file defines its own `run` task:

```
run {
    dependsOn pathingJar
    doFirst {
        classpath = files(
            "$buildDir/classes/java/main",
            "$buildDir/resources/main",
            pathingJar.archivePath)
    }

    Map<String, String> map = loadExecutionProperties()

    map.put("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "...")
    map.put("APP_NAME", "app-name")
    environment(map)
}
```

So I need to add `"$buildDir/classes/kotlin/main"` to files in classpath.

I hope this will help future users.